# REST resource exception interceptor

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, interceptor

I am trying to determine if it is possible to setup an interceptor like solution on a REST resource such that if an exception is thrown I can log the exception and change the response returned. I basically don't want to wrap all my REST resources with try/catch blocks. If a REST resource was managed I would just use an @Interceptor on all of my calls but since it is not managed that seems to be out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an implementation `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`. Let's suppose that your code might throw a `YourFancyException` from the resources. Then you can use the following mapper:

```
@Provider
public class YourFancyExceptionMapper 
                implements ExceptionMapper <YourFancyException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(YourFancyException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to annotate the mapper with `@Provider` and to make your resources methods to throw `YourFancyException`.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this on a per method basis? I don't want it to change legacy resources. Also if I made this for "Exception" would it catch all exceptions?

Comment: It works on a "per exception" basis, not "per method", but the mapper catches only the exceptions thrown from the resource methods. So, it should not be a problem with legacy resources as they, I guess, already deal with the exception with a try/catch. Yes, it catches all exceptions (thrown from resource methods) if you use a mapper for `Exception`.